# Laravel: return redirect after saving correctly throws SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: eloquent, save, laravel-artisan, laravel-6

I'm using Laravel 6.11 with MAMP and after saving correctly data form into my database table I got the following error.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name'
>   cannot be null (SQL: insert into `products` (`name`, `price`,
>   `description`, `long_description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (?, ?, ?, ?, 2020-02-05 19:00:35, 2020-02-05 19:00:35))
>   http://localhost:8000/admin/products

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/admin/products', 'ProductController@index'); 
Route::get('/admin/products/create', 'ProductController@create');
Route::get('/admin/products', 'ProductController@store');
```

**ProductController**

```php
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.products.create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->name = $request->input('name');
    $product->price = $request->input('price');
    $product->description = $request->input('description');
    $product->long_description = $request->input('long_description');
    $product->save(); //IT WORKS!! ALL DATA SAVED!!

    return redirect('/admin/products');
}
```

**Create.blade**

```
<form method="put" action="{{ url('/admin/products') }}">
.
.
```

Any ideas on how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because you have `two the same routes` declared. These are.

```
Route::get('/admin/products', 'ProductController@index');
Route::get('/admin/products', 'ProductController@store');
```

Now, when this line executed `redirect('/admin/products');`, Laravel will not invoke the first route you defined which is `Route::get('/admin/products', 'ProductController@index');`

rather invoke the last route you defined, the `Route::get('/admin/products', 'ProductController@store');`.

After invoking your store method in product controller, the method expect a request which includes the `name`, `price and etc.`.

Since you just redirected only without passing any argument, now laravel will throw you an error like what you had presented above.

To solve that, change your second route method for `ProductController@store`. Like this

```
Route::post('/admin/products', 'ProductController@store');
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the problem is related to having the route::get to the same url twice?

So I suppose it wants to redirect to index after the first time storing the product, it tries to store another product with no values.